# Multiple taps on the same row in a table view

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview

I am working on putting a checkbox in every row of a table view. When I tap a row, its value should get saved into an array, on tap of another row, its value should likewise get saved to the same array, and on a tap of the same row, the value should get deleted from the array.

Please suggest to me how to implement this one. I was using the following code in `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` method but I was not able to do it.

```
if([arrData count]==0)
{
    strlast = [arrName objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    [arrData addObject:strlast];
    NSLog(@"string checked in arrData   %@",strlast);
}
else 
{
    for(int i = 0 ;i < [arrData count]; i++) 
    {
        NSLog(@"[arrData count]:%d",[arrData count]);
        strSelected = [arrName objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        NSLog(@"strSelected:%@",strSelected);

        for(int i = 0 ;i < [arrData count]; i++) 
        {
            if([strSelected caseInsensitiveCompare:[arrData objectAtIndex:i]])
            {
                [arrData addObject:strSelected];
                NSLog(@"arrData:%@",arrData);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

list is the array name which contains all the data that is viewed in tableview replace it with your own array name
Suppose tableArray is your array in which values are inserted and deleted.
in .h file

```
NSMutableArray *tableArray;
```

in .m file in view didload

```
tableArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
```

tableview didselect row method:-

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {




if ([tableArray count]>0) {

        if ([tableArray containsObject:[list objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]]) {
            [tableArray removeObject:[list objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
            NSLog(@"data removed");
            NSLog(@"tableArray%@",tableArray);
        }
        else {
            [tableArray addObject:[list objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
            NSLog(@"data added");
            NSLog(@"tableArray%@",tableArray);
        }

    }
    else {
        //[tableArray addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",indexPath.row]];
        [tableArray addObject:[list objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
        NSLog(@"data added");
        NSLog(@"tableArray%@",tableArray);
    }


}
```

release the array in dealloc
I have tested the code I hope it might help you....

Comment: @Jenifer: the logic is right but , it returns the row number not the item on the row. i.e i have four name on four rows i want to get the operation on them

Comment: so if you are getting the rowno then you can find the item for that row no,its very simple

Comment: ok i understand see the edited answer it will give you the items at rows not the row no.